# X-cart css and categories image is not changing

Tags: php, e-commerce, x-cart

I was working on one of the client's site, using x-cart 4.7 version, the template is Reboot. I change their CSS file, but the site style is not changing.
I tried couple method, but still not changing, here's what I tried:

1. Rename the var/template_c to regenerate the cache. (<- template support suggest)
2. Uncheck Do not check if templates are changed, it's already unchecked.
3. I can't use http://www.yoursite.com/xcart/cleanup.php to clear cache. No folder and path found.

**I was thinking should use X-cart admin/template-name/template-clean up/ Clear templates/X-Cart cache** 
**Will this method delete a lot of things? Because can't back up the site and database, and I not really familiar with this platform.**

**Question2: Trying to change categories default image,** I changed the setting/Images location/categories-icon(or Banner System images
)it's not changing anything, but Product thumbnails/image is working.
I even change the file name in FTP still working, so I so confused where those image pulling from.

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Try locating which CSS file is loading on the page. Use web-dev-console for that or just view the page's source code. Temporarily untick the 'Use speed-up tool for CSS' checkbox on the 'Main page :: General settings :: General' before that.

Q2: There are 2 types of category images.
http://demo.x-cart.com/demo_goldplus/Computer-hardware/

1. Temporarily disable the 'Flyout Menus' module to localize the problem with category's menu icon.

2. The same solution as for Q1. Find out which path is used for the category image in the source code.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will try to look into it!